# Appstore connect create profile api doesn't work

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I work with appstore connect APIs. I used create profile api and i got 500 error (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/create_a_profile). I checked all fields and they are correct. I also contacted with apple but they did not return.

Request: [POST]: https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/profiles

Body data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "profileType": "IOS_APP_STORE"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "bundleId": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "xxx",
                    "type": "bundleIds"
                }
            },
            "certificates": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "xxx",
                    "type": "certificates"
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "profiles"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  errors: [
    {
      status: '500',
      code: 'UNEXPECTED_ERROR',
      title: 'An unexpected error occurred.',
      detail: 'An unexpected error occurred on the server side. If this issue ' +
        'continues, contact us at https://developer.apple.com/contact/.'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

Certificates data must be array

```
"certificates": {
      "data": {
            "id": "xxx",
            "type": "certificates"
      }
 }
```

to

```
"certificates": {
      "data": [{
            "id": "xxx",
            "type": "certificates"
      }]
 }
```